# Opencart content_bottom function

Tags: php, str-replace, opencart

In OpenCart (1.5.x) the variable `<?php echo $content_bottom; ?>` spits out much content including this message:

```
Welcome to My Site
Welcome to MySite.com, a company dedicated in giving you the best service while offering you the finest products – from genuine laptop batteries, laptop ac adapters/chargers, to LCD monitors – that are 100% genuine and proven to be of high quality that ensure you nothing but the best performance needed in order to give you the greatest satisfaction possible.
```

I want the variable only to remove that message only and continue to spit the rest of the information out (without removing whole contents)

Comment: This is an easy fix but it seems like a lot of people won't help you if you won't mark any of your answers as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open your **search.tpl** (I take it that is where it is being as I found your real site online)

**/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/search.tpl**

Find `<?php echo $content_bottom; ?>` and replace with:

```
<?
$my_message="<p>Welcome to My Site, Welcome to MySite.com, a company dedicated in giving you the best service while offering you the finest products – from genuine laptop batteries, laptop ac adapters/chargers, to LCD monitors – that are 100% genuine and proven to be of high quality that ensure you nothing but the best performance needed in order to give you the greatest satisfaction possible.</p>"
$spitFooter=str_replace($my_message, "", $content_bottom);
echo $spitFooter;
?>
```

Comment: str_replace may seem hacky but it works well in some instances where using the Opencart Admin WebSphere Commerce Console Management system does not suffice

Comment: i did it but it's showing this error , i just need to remove welcome content nor the whole feature products and homepage...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/genuineb/public_html/catalog/view/theme/MarketInSG_Fashion_Orange/template/product/search.tpl on line 241

Comment: Please can you post your full search.tpl and tell me exactly what text you want removing. Post in http://pastebin.com/

Comment: and see code above of  not_found.tpl and search file have same <?php echo $content_bottom; ?> tag see above for detail

Comment: Please post the full file codes in pastebin.com and also do you want the div box removed too or just the content inside the box.